# Exercise 1-6: (page 17 K&R) - getchar() question

Tags: c, char, getchar

When I run the program below, output give second 1. I debug the program, but I couldn't understand why compiler writing second 1 anytime?

[output like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a257v.png)

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
int c;

while (c = getchar() != EOF)
    printf("%d\n", c);
printf("%d - at EOF\n", c);
}
```

Comment: Due to [operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence), the expression `c = getchar() != EOF` is actually equal to `c = (getchar() != EOF)`. That is, you assign the boolean (`0` or `1`) result of `getchar() != EOF` to `c`. Is that intended?

Comment: Because when you press Enter, it's another character that is read by your code. Try typing something like this 'abc<Enter>'

Comment: thanks for your answers, you are right @Oo.oO. I missed Enter.

Comment: Even though the code does the right thing, I suggest you emphasize it by explicitly using parentheses around the condition. Also please add the actual problem this program is attempting to solve inside the question itself (as it's crucial to understand exactly what you're asking about). Questions should as much as possible be self-contained.

Comment: It is a solution for showing operator predence. This was my first question sorry for that @Someprogrammerdude. I will pay attention next time, thanks.

Comment: You might also want to take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Should make you better prepared for your next question. :)

Comment: I will look :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The <kbd>Enter</kbd> key you press to "send" the input from the terminal to the program is added in the input buffer as a newline `'\n'`, which will be read in the second iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

The condition in the while statement

```
while (c = getchar() != EOF)
```

is equivalent to

```
while (c = ( getchar() != EOF) )
```

due to the operator precedence. And this logical expression `getchar() != EOF` always yields `1` if the input was not interrupted.

You need to write

```
while ( ( c = getchar() ) != EOF)
```